# Generators and relations and realization of $D_n$ as a subgroup of a group of matrices $GL(2, \: \mathbb{Z}/(n))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove that the group  $\langle a, \: b \: | \: a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^n = 1 \rangle$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}/(n))$ and I know that it is $D_n$ (but I think it does not help me).

Comment: Welcome, now I think you can comment :D)

Comment: Why vote to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $D_n$ is generated by an element $r$ of order $n$ and an element $s$ of order $2$. We only need to define a representation $\rho\colon D_n\rightarrow GL_2(\Bbb Z/n)$ by specifying $\rho(r)$ and $\rho(s)$, satisfying the relations.
You could try
$$\rho(s)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you, with your help I have proved my statement.